# JPanel paint method misbehaves when obscured by menu items or tool tips

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, distortion

Basically, when a `JPanel` whose **`paintComponent` method overridden and applied `AffineTransform`**, obscured by other components like `JMenuItem` and `JToolTip` instances, some kind of transformation applies to it and causing distortion (creating gaps that do not painted).

This effect can be achieved by:

1. using `JSplitPane` to store panel
2. creating an animator (I've used Thread method) that constantly repaints this panel
3. Overriding the `paintComponent` method and using `setTransform( new_transform )` inside it.
4. Adding `JMenuBar` with tool tips that long enough to obscure the panel.

Answer (score 1):

*Cause of the problem:* Swing components uses their own graphics object that has AffineTransform applied to it. Whenever we used `graphics.setTransform( new_one )` this will erase the previous transform and this may create distortions, sometimes. This method should only be used when restoring the original transformation! ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setTransform(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform)))

*Solution:* Instead of applying transform directly as explained, do it step by step like:

```
AffineTransform af = graphics.getTransform();
af.translate(yours.getTranslateX(), yours.getTranslateY());  
af.scale(..);
...   // if you use other transforms like rotation, shearing etc. add them as well
graphics.setTransform(af);
```

Note: Always restore the original transform. Best way to do it is creating a copy of graphics object and dispose it afterwards.